# rename the file during transfer

Tags: powershell, rename, webdav

I want to upload a file to a suppliers webdav enviroment but my filename should be adjusted by the powershell script. I cannot rename the file in the source folder.

File users.csv should be renamed to AllADgroups_BI.csv

```
#Variables for your TOPdesk

$customerurl= 'xx'

$mypath = "E:\Shares\Supply Chain\topdesk\"

$myfile = "users.csv"

$uploadfolder = 'import'

$webdavuser = 'xx'

$applicationpassword = 'xx'

 

#Execute upload - Do not change below this line

$combineduserpassword = $webdavuser + ':' + $applicationpassword

$Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($combineduserpassword)

$EncodedAppPass =[Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)

$headers = @{

'Authorization' = 'BASIC ' + $EncodedAppPass

'Content-Type' = 'application/octet-stream'

}

 

$file = $mypath + $myfile

$url = "$customerurl/webdav/$uploadfolder/$myfile"

 

Write-Host "Uploading " $file " to " $url -NoNewLine

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method PUT -headers $headers -InFile $file
```

nothing yet because i have no idea how to change

Comment: Perhaps copy the file to a temp directory first with the required name and send it from there. Delete that copy afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

The $url is the location you are uploading to. To change the file name, just upload to a different file.

So, instead of
$url = "$customerurl/webdav/$uploadfolder/$myfile"

use something like
$url = "$customerurl/webdav/$uploadfolder/**newFileName.csv**"